# Command Prompts get automatically opens

Tags: terminal, windows-11

I don't why Windows Terminal opens always when I turn on my PC, or open it while it's on SLEEP 2-3 are opened with no new tab. I have to close them from Task Manager.

[image]

I have a feeling that some threat got installed with the game I found on internet.

Fix this problem please.

Comment: What you describe does not happen to a proper Windows system. Get Autoruns (Sysinternals) and see what is starting

Comment: @John you're jumping to conclusions too quickly. I actually too have this on my system. I've set that command prompt windows must always open in Windows Terminal. I also have a shortcut to execute `shutdown -h` to hibernate the computer. Whenever i now execute that shortcut, my computer goes to sleep, but the window now spawns another window and both are always open when I resume the pc and don't auto-close. This is a bug in Windows Terminal.

Comment: Windows is probably restoring the state of Windows Terminal prior to the shutdown.

Comment: Does it always open with the same page, and what is this page?

Comment: I was wondering if the page is actually a background. The terminal might have been customised tho

Comment: @JourneymanGeek if you look closely, the image is not in the center. I therefor concluded that the window was made semi transparent, and the image is the desktop background. This means that Windows Terminal restores a completely empty window.

Comment: Any comment from you @Ashutosh Mishra on information provided?

Comment: You're downloading games from untrustworthy sites? It's possibly you're infected, probable, even, but that doesn't necessarily explain what you're seeing. Most infections try to hide themselves. I suggest you not do what you've been doing.